# How to keep thousand separator by writing pandas df in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a question about writing `pandas` dataframe into Excel. I have numbers with thousand separator as `.`, after writing to Excel it changes to `,`. How can I write my data without changing the separator?

This is how it looks in Jupyter notebook:

[image]

And here is how it looks in Excel:

[image]

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
sheet=wb[s_name]
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

pivot_to_excel(wb, filename, prepared_data, s_name, writer)

def pivot_to_excel(book, excelfilename, PivotTable, s_name, writer):
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
    for sheetname in writer.sheets:
        if (sheetname==s_name):            
            PivotTable.to_excel(writer,sheet_name=sheetname, startrow=writer.sheets[sheetname].max_row, index = False
```

UPD:
If my data is mixed like this, it seems correct after writing in excel:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suggest you look at how excel is displaying the thousand separator.

Comment: Have you tried this? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e

Comment: Excel just stores the thing as a number, how that number appears in excel's UI is just "Formatting". So change the format of those cells to use a period as the thousand separator, but note that the underlying data is still the same.